# rigidbody.velocity vs lerp efficiency in Unity3D

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine

I have two ways of moving GameObjects:

Method 1

```
void Update(){
    rigidbody.velocity = ( targetPosition - transform.position )*speed;
}
```

Method 2

```
void Update(){
    transform.position = Vector3.lerp( transform.position, targetPosition, Time.delta*speed);
}
```

Which one is more efficient? Does rigidbody.velocity use the GPU?

**Edit**

I develop for mobile platforms so I would like to know if performance might vary considerably between the two methods.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the question

> Which one is more efficient?

is `transform.position`

This is because using `transform.position` directly modifies the position of the `GameObject`'s `Transform` component which controls the position, orientation, and scaling of said object.

Using `rigidbody.velocity` modifies this transform using the Physics system which can be slower than just directly setting the value.

But I have to stress that this is an extreme case of premature optimization, and the difference between the two in terms of performance is negligible. The only difference you should be concerned about is how using these different methods to move objects fits into your game design.

Typically, `transform.position` should only be used in two cases: (1) instantaneous transportation (spawning, teleportation, etc.) or (2) objects that do not use the physics system (ie don't move based on gravity, friction, or other factors).

On the other hand, using `rigidbody.velocity` is used to provide more realistic movement behavior based on the physics system.

Which one to use should be based on the design of the game and the current object, and not be determined by "which one is more efficient?"

Comment: My main concern is that rigidbody.velocity might affect the frame rate when many objects are moving since I develop for mobile platforms.

Comment: I guess this just depends on the question of "how many is many?" Again I would advocate that worrying about it now is a case of premature optimization, and should only be dealt with if in the future if this is determined to be a bottleneck through the use of the profiler.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have a lot of code already implemented with lerp, but I am want to start animating with physics to give the user a richer experience. While I can just write the differential equations for the position and the velocity (as a sometimes do), using unity's internals seems safer, just wanted to know the performance cost.
About the quantity of the moving game objects. I don't expect to move more than 10 at a time.

Comment: My main development with Unity has been on the PC, but I have done some small amount of handheld development. In my experience, I never had an issue with moving objects of that amount using the `RigidBody`